# What is the greatest possible perimeter of a right-angled triangle with integer side lengths if one of the sides has length 12?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, inequality

> What is the greatest possible perimeter of a right-angled triangle with integer side lengths if
> one of the sides has length 12 ?

I know this question can be done in a variety of ways, the answer comes out to be $84$.

However, my friend and I were trying this question using QM$\ge$AM, and we didn't get $84$ through that, so I decided to ask here.

Let $x,y,z$ be the sides, and $x=12$.

We have:

$$\sqrt{\frac{x^2+y^2+z^2}{3}} \ge \frac{x+y+z}{3}$$

And $x,y,z$ are +ve because length can't be negative.

Since we want the maximum value the perimeter, the equality of the expression holds at $x=y=z$

plugging in the values, I get the maximum perimeter as $36$. Why am I getting the wrong answer solving this way?

I would be grateful if someone helped. Thanks.

Comment: $x=y=z$ gives you an equilateral triangle. Your question is about **right triangle**, that doesn't get addressed in your approach.

Comment: Yes, you're right. Thanks, however using this inequality shouldn't we be getting the maximum perimeter in all possible cases (including all triangles)?

Comment: Your approach can't be right because if you scale up a $3$-$4$-$5$ right triangle by a factor of $4$, you get a perimeter of $48$.

Comment: @Mathematica The issue is that the inequality you are using is about three positive numbers $x,y,z$, whereas in your problem you want $x,y,z$ to be the sides of a triangle, so they are not **just any** numbers, they should satisfy constraints like triangle inequality etc. and that is why your approach won't yield the results.

Comment: yeahh got it thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Euclid algorithm.  $a=2mn=12$, max possible with $m=6$ and $n=1$ gives $b=m^2-n^2=35$ and $c=m^2+n^2=37$ so perimeter $=84$.

Comment: Trying $b=m^2-n^2=12$ leads to $m=4$ and $n=2$ as the only possibility, making $a=2mn=16$ and $c=m^2+n^2=20$ for a total of $48 \lt 84$.

Comment: The Euclid algorithm does not generate all Pythagorean triangles.  It produces all the primitive ones, but it will not produce $9,12,15$, for example.  In this case it finds the one we want.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative approach.

Either $(12)$ is the hypotenuse or it is one of the legs.  The analysis below, which assumes that $(12)$ is one of the legs, will clearly show that setting $(12)$ as the hypotenuse will not maximize the perimeter.

Therefore, you have that $144 = (12)^2 = (x^2 - y^2) = (x + y)(x - y)$.

Here, it is desired to maximize $(x + y)$, so the possibility of $(x + y) = 144$ must be examined.  This can be seen as impossible, because it requires that $x,y$ have the same odd/even parity, which makes it impossible for $(x - y)$ to equal $1$.

Therefore, the maximum value for $(x + y)$ is $72$, which requires that $(x - y) = 2.$  This is achieved via $(x,y) = (37,35).$

Comment: Just a quick note: $12$ cannot be the length of the hypotenuse because $12$ cannot be written as sum of squares of two integers. So that case can be ruled out easily.

Comment: @AnuragA true, but requires some analysis to prove.  My way, no such corresponding analysis is required, because it becomes irrelevant whether $(12)$ can be a hypotenuse.